# MSBuild exec task with for

Tags: msbuild, exec, for-loop

I am trying to run the following commands as part of an MSBuild script:

```
for /R . %f in (*.targets) do copy /Y "%f" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microso
ft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild"
```

The commands is implemented in an exec the following way:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)" Command="for /R . %f in (*.targets) do copy /Y &quot;%f&quot; &quot;$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild&quot;" />
```

The command works fine from console, but when trying to run it from MSBuild I get the error:

```
Task "Exec"
  Command:
  for /R . %f in (*.targets) do copy /Y "%f" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild"
  f" "C:\Program was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\rd-build\AppData\Local\Temp\OH Test2\Continuous.BuildTargets\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(98,5): error MSB3073: The command "for /R . %f in (*.targets) do copy /Y "%f" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild"" exited with code 255.
Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just explained in your previous question. In that case you need to add extra % in front of your variables. It is explained in help of FOR command as follows

> To use the FOR command in a batch
>   program, specify %%variable instead of
>   %variable.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use %% and not %.