# Can you use a 'for %i' loop in a msbuild exec command?

Tags: for-loop, msbuild

I tried to use this in a build file but apparently this is not correct:

```
<Exec Command='for %i in (*) do echo %i'/>
```

It gives the message:

"i was unexpected at this time".

My goal was to delete specific files in a directory, for example like this:

'for %i in (*) do if not %i == name1 if not %i == name2 del %i'

So I want to delete the files in a folder except for the two files with name1 and name2. This is probably not the way I should try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585260/msbuild-exec-task-with-for), you'll have to escape `%` as `%%`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the novice question, pretty much on my own in the office, nobody to ask these silly things. :-)

Comment: No worries, we've all been there — and msbuild is not the most transparent environment of all times